# Visifire.Charts How to disable vertical lines. WP

Tags: windows-phone-7, charts, visifire

Chart is created by code. But I can't disable vertical lines in chart.
It is a code of creating chart:

```
        public void CreateChart() {
        CleanChart();

        visiChart = new Chart()
        {
            ToolTipEnabled = true,
            Width = 400,
            Height = 200,
            Padding = new Thickness(0),
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 6, 0, -12),
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
        };

        ChartGrid grid = new ChartGrid()
        {
            Enabled = false
        };
        DataSeries dataSeries = new DataSeries();
        DataPoint dataPoint;
        Axis yAx = new Axis()
        {
            AxisLabels = new AxisLabels() { Enabled = false },
            Grids = new ChartGridCollection() {grid}
        };

        int i = 0;
        var deps = App.CurrentAgreement.Deposits.Deposit.Where(x => x.DepositIliv + x.DepositLink > 0).ToList();

        foreach (var dep in deps) {
            dataPoint = new DataPoint();
            dataPoint.YValue = dep.DepositIliv + dep.DepositLink + dep.UValue + dep.WarrantyValue;
            dataPoint.XValue = i;
            i++;
            dataPoint.LabelText = dataPoint.YValue.Out();
            dataPoint.AxisXLabel = DateTime.Parse(dep.DepositDate).ToString("MMM yyyy");
            dataPoint.MouseLeftButtonUp += dataPoint_MouseLeftButtonUp;
            dataSeries.DataPoints.Add(dataPoint);
        }
        dataSeries.LabelEnabled = true;
        dataSeries.RenderAs = RenderAs.Column;
        dataSeries.Color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        visiChart.Series.Add(dataSeries);
        visiChart.AxesY.Add(yAx);

        ChartPlaceHolder.Children.Add(visiChart);
    }
```

But i dont need vertical lines visible. It is a screen of chart.

[image: chart]

How i can disable lines??
Help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable the Grid lines from AxisX also.

Example:

```
ChartGrid grid = new ChartGrid()
{
    Enabled = false
};

Axis xAx = new Axis();
xAx.Grids.Add(grid);
visiChart.AxesX.Add(xAx);
```